# Cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor doesn't fill the proper color

Tags: c#, excel

I need to mark error cells in my output excel file in red. If in the original document those cells have no fill, all is fine, the color is red. But if the cell was already filled with Blue (or some kind of), in the output it become filled with pink, but not with red! 
Here is my code:

```
var cell = worksheet.Cells[row, column];
        cell.Reset();
        cell.Value = string.Format("{0}  Error:{1}", cell.Value, errortext);
        cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Empty);
        cell.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
        cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
```

This is how it should look:

[image: This is how it should look]

This is how it is if the original fill was blue:

[image: This is how it is if the original fill was blue]

Will be very appreciated for any help.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `.SetColor` all those times - only the last one matters. I think you have some conditional formatting overriding your `SetColor` - what happens when you manually set the cell to BG Color Red using the Ribbon?

Comment: I know it is not needed to repeat `.SetColor `, I've just tried some options. When manually set the Red - all is fine, it is red.

Comment: do you have conditional formatting? Is there a theme on this workbook? Does the cell use a 'cell style'?

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Tint = 0;
```

that helped.